How to sample rows of dataset repeatedly based on a certain column in R?
Consider the following dataset:
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2),
                 v1 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10))

My intention is to sample randomly (with replacement) rows of size n=3 for unique id. Let's say we repeat this two times for each id. Finally, the sampled dataset should be saved or stored in a data frame. To be more precise, the new dataset has the following form.
id  v1
1   1
1   4
1   5
1   2
1   2
1   3
2   7
2   8
2   9
2   6
2   7
2   10

Any help is highly appreciated!

What does rows of size n=3 for unique id mean? Also, why repeat 2 times for each id? library(dplyr); set.seed(42); df %>% mutate(sample(v1, replace=T), .by = id) gives a result similar to what your expected result should be.

By "rows of size n=3", I mean that we should select three rows at a time. That means, if we repeat 2 times, each id has 6 rows in a new data set.

Maybe df %>% reframe(v1 = sample(v1, 2*3, replace=T), .by = id) then.
